# Adding a single character to add keys in Counter

Tags: python, string, dictionary, counter, key-value

If the type of a Counter object's keys is `str`, i.e.:

I could do this:

```
>>> vocab_counter = Counter("the lazy fox jumps over the brown dog".split())

>>> vocab_counter  = Counter({k+u"\uE000":v for k,v in vocab_counter.items()})
>>> vocab_counter
Counter({'brown\ue000': 1,
         'dog\ue000': 1,
         'fox\ue000': 1,
         'jumps\ue000': 1,
         'lazy\ue000': 1,
         'over\ue000': 1,
         'the\ue000': 2})
```

**What would be a quick and/or pythonic way to add a character to all keys?**

Is the above method the only way to achieve the final counter with the character appended to all keys? Are there other way(s) to achieve the same goal?

Comment: I think the way you are doing it seems pretty good... what kind of improvements are you expecting? Time taken? Lines of code?

Comment: Not lines of code, just wondering whether there's a better way. Running through all keys multiple times isn't very optimal. Maybe I've to dump it to a dataframe or numpy array and then read it back to counter.

Comment: I don't think that would be better... That way would involve creating the list of split strings, manipulating every single one of them, then counting them. The way it's currently being down only touches each unique word - so if counting a novel it would be much more clean and efficient (in my opinion anyway) the only change I'd make is creating a dictionary instead of a counter on your last step, as you don't need to count anymore (I assume)

Comment: hi @alvas  don't know about multiple time but you have to iterate for at-least one time to update. check my answer. it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way would be adding that character before creating your counter object. You can do it using a generator expression within `Counter`:

```
In [15]: vocab_counter = Counter(w + u"\uE000" for w in "the lazy fox jumps over the brown dog".split())

In [16]: vocab_counter
Out[16]: Counter({'the\ue000': 2, 'fox\ue000': 1, 'dog\ue000': 1, 'jumps\ue000': 1, 'lazy\ue000': 1, 'over\ue000': 1, 'brown\ue000': 1})
```

If it's not possible to modify the words before creating the Counter you can override the `Counter` object in order to add the special character [during setting the values for keys](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__).

Answer (score 1):

The only other optimised way I can think of is to use a subclass of `Counter` that appends the character when the key is inserted:

```
from collections import Counter


class CustomCounter(Counter):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if len(key) > 1 and not key.endswith(u"\uE000"):
            key += u"\uE000"
        super(CustomCounter, self).__setitem__(key, self.get(key, 0) + value)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> CustomCounter("the lazy fox jumps over the brown dog".split())
CustomCounter({u'the\ue000': 2, u'fox\ue000': 1, u'brown\ue000': 1, u'jumps\ue000': 1, u'dog\ue000': 1, u'over\ue000': 1, u'lazy\ue000': 1})
# With both args and kwargs 
>>> CustomCounter("the lazy fox jumps over the brown dog".split(), **{'the': 1, 'fox': 3})
CustomCounter({u'fox\ue000': 4, u'the\ue000': 3, u'brown\ue000': 1, u'jumps\ue000': 1, u'dog\ue000': 1, u'over\ue000': 1, u'lazy\ue000': 1})
```

Comment: The CustomCounter in the demo contains the entry `u'the\ue000': 1` which should have value 2, so it seems like there's an error in this solution.

Comment: @Felix Oopsy! fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest way i used is,

```
vocab_counter = Counter("the lazy fox jumps over the brown dog".split()) 
for key in vocab_counter.keys():
  vocab_counter[key+u"\uE000"] = vocab_counter.pop(key)
```

Comment: The `'\ue000'` should be at the end of each new key, not the front.

Comment: Yah! you can consider this as typo :P

Comment: Now that that's been fixed, I think this is the only error-free answer here.  I don't think this method is any better than what was in the question, but at least it's not worse.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with string manipulations:

```
text = 'the lazy fox jumps over the brown dog'
Counter((text + ' ').replace(' ', '_abc ').strip().split())
```