# Creating a custom Counter object with special set function

Tags: python, oop, dictionary, counter

From [Adding a single character to add keys in Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177876/adding-a-single-character-to-add-keys-in-counter) , @AshwiniChaudhary gave an excellent answer to create a new `Counter` object with a different set() function:

```
from collections import Counter

class CustomCounter(Counter):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if len(key) > 1 and not key.endswith(u"\uE000"):
            key += u"\uE000"
        super(CustomCounter, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

To allow user-defined char/str to append to the key, I've tried:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

class AppendedStrCounter(Counter):
    def __init__(self, str_to_append):
        self._appended_str = str_to_append
        super(AppendedStrCounter, self).__init__()
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if len(key) > 1 and not key.endswith(self._appended_str):
            key += self._appended_str
        super(AppendedStrCounter, self).__setitem__(tuple(key), value)
```

But it's returning an empty Counter:

```
>>> class AppendedStrCounter(Counter):
...     def __init__(self, str_to_append):
...         self._appended_str = str_to_append
...         super(AppendedStrCounter, self).__init__()
...     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
...         if len(key) > 1 and not key.endswith(self._appended_str):
...             key += self._appended_str
...         super(AppendedStrCounter, self).__setitem__(tuple(key), value)
... 
>>> AppendedStrCounter('foo bar bar blah'.split())
AppendedStrCounter()
```

That's because I'm missing the iter in the `__init__()`:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

class AppendedStrCounter(Counter):
    def __init__(self, iter, str_to_append):
        self._appended_str = str_to_append
        super(AppendedStrCounter, self).__init__(iter)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if len(key) > 1 and not key.endswith(self._appended_str):
            key += self._appended_str
        super(AppendedStrCounter, self).__setitem__(tuple(key), value)
```

[out]:

```
>>> AppendedStrCounter('foo bar bar blah'.split(), u'\ue000')
AppendedStrCounter({('f', 'o', 'o', '\ue000'): 1, ('b', 'a', 'r', '\ue000'): 1, ('b', 'l', 'a', 'h', '\ue000'): 1})
```

But the value for `'bar'` is wrong, it should be 2 instead of 1.

**Is using `iter` to the `__init__()` the right way to initialize the `Counter`?**

Comment: You're making the assumption that the superclass constructor uses `__setitem__` for each item it adds, but there's no guarantee that it must. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter only promises how its constructor will behave, not how it is implemented.

Comment: Take a close look at the referenced answer of @AshwiniChaudhary. In the example in his answer, the counter of the "the" key is also 1 instead of 2

Comment: Changing how keys are stored could have some nasty surprises...  For example, no one can store `'word\ue000'` counts separately from `'word'` in that `CustomCounter`.  Also, how do they get specific words back out?  The user has to remember to ask for `cc['word\ue000']` whenever they want `cc['word']`, which completely defeats the OOP goal of encapsulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in
[Felix's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196793#comment73466405_43196793),
[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)
does not document *how* its `__init__` method adds keys or sets values, only that it does.
Since it is not explicitly designed for subclassing, the wisest thing to do is *not* subclass it.

The
[`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html)
module exists to provide easily-subclassed abstract classes of Python's builtin types, including `dict`
(`MutableMapping`, in ABC terms).
So, if all you need is "a `Counter`-like class"
(as opposed to "a subclass of `Counter` that will satisfy builtins like `isinstance` and `issubclass`),
you can create your own `MutableMapping` that has-a `Counter`, and then "middleman" the initializer and the three methods that `Counter` adds to the typical `dict`:

```
import collections
import collections.abc


def _identity(s):
    '''
    Default mutator function.
    '''
    return s


class CustomCounter(collections.abc.MutableMapping):
    '''
    Overrides the 5 methods of a MutableMapping:
    __getitem__, __setitem__, __delitem__, __iter__, __len__

    ...and the 3 non-Mapping methods of Counter:
    elements, most_common, subtract
    '''

    def __init__(self, values=None, *, mutator=_identity):
        self._mutator = mutator
        if values is None:
            self._counter = collections.Counter()
        else:
            values = (self._mutator(v) for v in values)
            self._counter = collections.Counter(values)
        return

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._counter[self._mutator(item)]

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        self._counter[self._mutator(item)] = value
        return

    def __delitem__(self, item):
        del self._counter[self._mutator(item)]
        return

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._counter)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._counter)

    def __repr__(self):
        return ''.join([
          self.__class__.__name__,
          '(',
          repr(dict(self._counter)),
          ')'
          ])

    def elements(self):
        return self._counter.elements()

    def most_common(self, n):
        return self._counter.most_common(n)

    def subtract(self, values):
        if isinstance(values, collections.abc.Mapping):
            values = {self._mutator(k): v for k, v in values.items()}
            return self._counter.subtract(values)
        else:
            values = (self._mutator(v) for v in values)
            return self._counter.subtract(values)


def main():
    def mutator(s):
        # Asterisks are easier to print than '\ue000'.
        return '*' + s + '*'

    words = 'the lazy fox jumps over the brown dog'.split()

    # Test None (allowed by collections.Counter).
    ctr_none = CustomCounter(None)
    assert 0 == len(ctr_none)

    # Test typical dict and collections.Counter methods.
    ctr = CustomCounter(words, mutator=mutator)
    print(ctr)
    assert 1 == ctr['dog']
    assert 2 == ctr['the']
    assert 7 == len(ctr)
    del(ctr['lazy'])
    assert 6 == len(ctr)
    ctr.subtract(['jumps', 'dog'])
    assert 0 == ctr['dog']
    assert 6 == len(ctr)
    ctr.subtract({'the': 5, 'bogus': 100})
    assert -3 == ctr['the']
    assert -100 == ctr['bogus']
    assert 7 == len(ctr)
    return


if "__main__" == __name__:
    main()
```

Output (line-wrapped, for ease of reading):

```
CustomCounter({
  '*brown*': 1,
  '*lazy*': 1,
  '*the*': 2,
  '*over*': 1,
  '*jumps*': 1,
  '*fox*': 1,
  '*dog*': 1
  })
```

I added a keyword-only argument to the initializer, `mutator`, to store the function that converts real-world whatevers to the "mutant" counted versions.
Note that this likely means that `CustomCounter` no longer stores "hashable objects", but "hashable objects that don't make the mutator barf".

Also, if the standard library's `Counter` ever gets new methods, you'll have to update `CustomCounter` to "override" them.
(You could maybe work around that by using
[`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)
to pass any unknown attributes to `self._counter`, but any keys in the arguments will be handed to the `Counter` in their raw, "un-mutated" form.

Finally, as I noted before, it's not *actually* a subclass of `collections.Counter`, if other code is specifically looking for one.